# Navigation drawer with fragments and only one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Im doing an app with navigation drawer.
For this, i have a HomeActivity, this contains all the login of my navigation drawer, the options in menu, the view, the titles etc. And here, i set listenerclick for navigation elements.
This listener receives FragmentManager and with a switch do:

```
        smf.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_content, new Fragment()).commit();
```

Replacing fragment for the fragment that i need in each case of switch.

In home layout i have a framelayout and navigation drawer.

Mi question is, is correct that i only have one activity with a framelayout, and depends on the item clicked in navigation drawer i replace the fragment on the frame, or is better have lot of activitys, and create menu in all of them with the same login, and when user click in item menu, launch new intent with the activity selected?

I hope i have explained ok...

Thank you.

Comment: This way is okay. Using fragments, it can get easier for you to support multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the response, then i will continue in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I did this same thing, but I found it was a lot better to have different activities.

If you do go down the separate activities path you should have one base activity that the activities extend so you don't need to rewrite the drawer code.

A fragment is only really meant to be an extension of an activity, for example when you have multiple tabs, or you are swiping between different views, or you need to break up your activity into sections.